# Why do we have this relation between $\frac{\sin \left(\pi x\right)}{\pi }$ and $x!$?

Tags: functions

https://www.desmos.com/calculator/jpbffl8fhe

Why do we have $\frac{x}{(x!(-x)!)}$ = $\frac{\sin \left(\pi x\right)}{\pi }$ ?

With gamma functions that gives us : $\frac{x}{(\Gamma(x+1)\Gamma(-x+1))}$ = $\frac{\sin \left(\pi x\right)}{\pi }$

[Prove that $\Gamma(p)\times \Gamma(1-p)=\frac{\pi}{\sin (p\pi)},\: \forall p \in (0,\: 1)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/714482/prove-that-gammap-times-gamma1-p-frac-pi-sin-p-pi-forall-p-in) tells us that $\left(x-1\right)!\left(-x\right)!$ = $\frac{\pi }{\sin \left(\pi x\right)}$, maybe I can make something out of it ?

Comment: State the factorials in terms of gamma functions. [Euler's Reflection Formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_formula).

Comment: What is $x$? $x \in \mathbb{N}$?

Comment: @snarski x! = gamma(x+1)

Comment: Would [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/714482) answer you question ?

Comment: @Lucian But that proof is for $(\Gamma(x)\Gamma(-x+1))$ = $\frac{\pi }{\sin \left(\pi x\right)}$ .. how do I turn it into $(\Gamma(x+1)\Gamma(-x+1))$ = $\frac{x\pi }{\sin \left(\pi x\right)}$ ?

Comment: By definition, $\Gamma(x+1)=x\Gamma(x)$.

Comment: @Lucian Oh thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proof given in math.stackexchange.com/questions/714482 gives a direct answer

It proves that $$\Gamma(p)\times \Gamma(1-p)=\frac{\pi}{\sin (p\pi)},\: \forall  p \in (0,\: 1)$$Which is exactly the question here knowing that $\Gamma(x)=\frac{\Gamma(x+1)}{x}$