# Why does $\frac1{x!(-x)!}= \frac{\sin{\pi x}}{\pi x}$?

Tags: functions

I was playing around in Desmos and found this interesting relationship. Where does it come from? I got $\frac1{x!(-x)!}= \frac{\sin{\pi x}}{\pi x}$. Why does this happen?

[image]

Comment: Have a look here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function and here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_formula

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do we have this relation between $\frac{\sin \left(\pi x\right)}{\pi }$ and $x!$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/803443/why-do-we-have-this-relation-between-frac-sin-left-pi-x-right-pi-and)

Comment: One shouldn't downvote such questions: they are natural ones !