# Definite integral

Tags: integration, trigonometry, definite-integrals, gamma-function

So I was playing around with Euler's Reflection Formula ($\Gamma(s)\Gamma(1-s)=\frac{\pi}{\sin(\pi s)}$), trying to prove it with calculus, and was able to reduce $$ \Gamma(s)\Gamma(1-s)=2\int_0^{\pi/2}\tan^{2s-1}(x)\,\text dx\;\;(0<s<1) $$

But I have no idea how to show $$ 2\int_0^{\pi/2}\tan^{2s-1}(x)\,\text dx=\frac{\pi}{\sin(\pi s)} $$

I have been able to substitute to find that it is the same integral as $$ 2\int_1^\infty\frac{1}{x(x^2-1)^{1-s}}\text dx=\int_1^\infty\frac{1}{x(x-1)^{1-s}}\text dx $$
But can't get any further.

Any ideas?

Comment: Other approaches can be found [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/714482).

Comment: Thanks, that's more what I was looking for @Lucian.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\wt}[1]{\widetilde{#1}}$
With $\ds{\sin\pars{x} \equiv t}$:
\begin{align}&\color{#c00000}{%
\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\tan^{2s - 1}\pars{x}\,\dd x}
=\int_{0}^{1}{t^{2s - 1} \over \pars{1 - t^{2}}^{s - 1/2}}
\,{\dd t \over \pars{1 - t^{2}}^{1/2}}
=\int_{0}^{1}{t^{s - 1/2} \over \pars{1 - t}^{s}}\,\half\,t^{-1/2}\,\dd t
\\[3mm]&=\half\int_{0}^{1}t^{s - 1}\pars{1 - t}^{-s}\,\dd t
=\half\,{\Gamma\pars{s}\Gamma\pars{-s + 1} \over \Gamma\pars{1}}
=\half\,{\pi \over \sin\pars{\pi s}}
\end{align}

> $$
> \color{#44f}{\large 2\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\tan^{2s - 1}\pars{x}\,\dd x
> ={\pi \over \sin\pars{\pi s}}}\,,\qquad\qquad 0 < \Re\pars{s} < 1
> $$

See [this link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function).

Comment: . . . nice . . .