# Show $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{-z}}{(1 + x)^{2}} ~ \mathrm{d}{x} = \frac{\pi z}{sin(\pi z)}$

Tags: special-functions, contour-integration, factorial, gamma-function, beta-function

I need to solve the following integral:
$$
I = \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{-z}}{(1 + x)^{2}} ~ \mathrm{d}{x}.
$$

---

Wolfram Alpha gives the answer as $ \frac{\pi z}{sin(\pi z)}$, or equivalently, $\pi z csc(\pi z)$

My ultimate goal is to demonstrate that $z!(-z)! = \frac{\pi z}{sin(\pi z)}$

So far, I arrived at this integral by gamma and beta functions:

$$
z!(-z)! = \Gamma(z+1)\Gamma(-z+1) = \Gamma(m)\Gamma(n)\\
= B(z+1,-z+1)\Gamma(m+n) = B(z+1,-z+1)\Gamma(2)\\
\\
=B(z+1,-z+1) = \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{-z+1-1}}{(1 + x)^{2}} ~ \mathrm{d}{x}\\ 
= \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{-z}}{(1 + x)^{2}} ~ \mathrm{d}{x} 
$$

This integral is effectively the answer. Can you solve this with a contour integral? Also, is there a special name for this integral?

Comment: i got this here $$\pi \,\csc \left( \pi \,z \right) z$$

Comment: how did you get this?

Comment: A [related](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/714482) question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By considering the contour integral

$$\oint_C d\zeta \frac{\zeta^{-z}}{(1+\zeta)^2} $$

about a keyhole contour and using the residue theorem, we may derive the relation

$$\left (1-e^{-i 2 \pi z} \right) \int_0^{\infty} dx \frac{x^{-z}}{(1+x)^2} = i 2 \pi \left [\frac{d}{d\zeta} e^{-z \log{\zeta}} \right ]_{\zeta=e^{i \pi}} = i 2 \pi (-z e^{-i \pi} ) e^{-i \pi z}$$

The result follows after a little algebra.

Comment: Can you show the algebra please? I don't see that result. Are you using Euler's formula to get there?

Comment: @khaverim: yes.  Plus $e^{i \pi z}-e^{-i \pi z} = i 2 \sin{\pi z}$.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\on}[1]{\operatorname{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
&\bbox[5px,#ffd]{\int_{0}^{\infty}
{x^{-z} \over \pars{1 + x}^{2}}\,\dd x} =
\int_{0}^{\infty}
x^{-z}\bracks{\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}{-2 \choose k}x^{k}}\,\dd x
\\[5mm] = &\
\int_{0}^{\infty}
x^{-z}\bracks{\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}{k + 1 \choose k}
\pars{-1}^{k}x^{k}}\,\dd x
\\[5mm] = &\
\int_{0}^{\infty}
x^{\pars{\color{red}{1 - z}} - 1}\bracks{\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}\color{red}{\Gamma\pars{2 + k}}
{\pars{-x}^{k} \over k!}}\,\dd x
\\[5mm] = &\
\Gamma\pars{\color{red}{1 - z}}
\Gamma\pars{2 - \bracks{\color{red}{1 - z}}} =
\Gamma\pars{1 - z}\Gamma\pars{z}z\quad
\pars{\substack{\mbox{Ramanujan's}\\[0.5mm] \mbox{Master}
\\[1mm] \mbox{Theorem}}}
\\[5mm] = &\
\bbx{\pi z \over \sin\pars{\pi z}} \\ &
\end{align}